# __fp16 type undefined in GNU ARM C++

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, half-precision-float

I'm trying to use type `__fp16` (half precision float) in program compiled with GNU ARM C++ Compiler however whenever I try to declare variable of this type I get an error message `__fp16 is not declared`. I assume that it's caused by the fact that I lack some header file, but I was unable to find any data on which header it might be. Does anybody know where it's defined / what shall I include?

Comment: Does your target architecture support half-precision floats?

Answer (score 4):

Yes the target supports half precision operations; it doesn't support doubles.

I got a reply from the GNU team. The solution is to add the compiler command `-mfp16-format=ieee`. That defines `__fp16` to ieee standard (see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html)

Comment: [*The `_Float16` type is supported on AArch64 systems by default, and on ARM systems when the IEEE format for 16-bit floating-point types is selected with `-mfp16-format=ieee`*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Floating-Types.html)